# What is this fitting in my 2" stack?

Tags: plumbing, pvc, plumbing-fixture

What is that wide-diameter fitting in my 2" PVC stack?

It's in the way of the hardwood floor and the drywall. Can it be effectively removed?

[image]

Comment: I can't be positive but I think it is a check valve. I would not remove it - perhaps lower it a few inches but do not remove it. Prevents back flow.

Comment: What's the pipe for? Apparently it isn't a typical drain stack, which wouldn't require a check valve, which is apparently needed here for some reason.